# Jackson FasterXML - @JsonManagedReference e @JsonBackReference

Tags: json, spring, jackson

Estou usando as anotações `@JsonManagedReference` e `@JsonBackReference` para mapear meu relacionamento bidirecional, com isso consegui eliminar o bug de loop infinito, mas acarretou em outro problema.

Tenho duas telas para edição de estrutura simples de funcionário, empresa e grupo.

Em uma das telas "edição de grupos" eu tenho um agrupamento de empresas onde posso adicionar uma lista de empresas que fazem parte deste grupo, esta tela está funcionando OK.

A segunda tela de "edição de funcionários" eu posso vincular um funcionário a uma empresa. Nesta tela existe um grid que exibe os dados dos funcionários relacionamento sua empresa e grupo.

Nessa tela o grid está preenchido até empresa, já no grupo a informação é nula. Tenho certeza que meu backend está trazendo a informação correta, em meus debugs antes de retornar as informações para o frontend as minhas entidades estão preenchidas corretamente (tenho a entidade grupo preenchida), creio que o problema é no Jackson, na hora de converter minha lista em um JSON, quando retorna do backend o meu "grupo" já é nulo no JSON.

```
public class Funcionario {

   private int id;

   private String nome;

   private Empresa empresa;
}



public class Empresa {

   private int id;

   private String nome;

   @JsonBackReference
   private Grupo grupo;
}



public class Grupo {

   private int id;

   private String nome;

   @JsonManagedReference
   private List<Empresa> empresas
}
```

Comment: Você entende que as anotações que você está utilizando irá ignorar um dos lados?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo, entendo sim, creio que me expressei mal. Gostaria de saber as alternativas corretas para esse caso, acabei utilizando a notação @JsonIdentityInfo para mapear uma outra instancia  da empresa dentro do Funcionario (isso pois utilizo somente na visualização do grid). Mas talvez exista uma forma mais elegante de fazer isso que eu não esteja encontrando. Obrigado

Comment: Olha amigo, existem outras alternativas sim, mas está mais comum de ver o pessoal usar o @JsonIgnore, está caindo em desuso essas duas anotações que você esta utilizando.